# Automatically register trigger callbacks for selected methods in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, eventtrigger

I need to be able to expose one object's methods to be called by event triggers. I also want to register these triggers automatically by providing a list of methods and their arguments for a given object. Here is what I have ([jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hVGcE/2/)):

```
function A() {
}
A.prototype = {
    register: function(cbname, cbargs, context) {
        args = ['context'].concat(cbargs);
        var callback = new Function(args, "context." + cbname + "(" + cbargs.toString() + ");");
        $(document).bind(cbname, callback);
        document.write(callback.toString() + "<br />");
    }
};

function B() {
}
B.prototype = {
    add: function(l, r) {
        document.write(l + r);
    }
};


$(function() {
    var a = new A();
    var b = new B();
    a.register('add', ['l', 'r'], b);
    $(document).trigger('add', [b, 1, 2]);
});​
```

The created callback has what seems to be the correct code: `function anonymous(context,l,r) { context.add(l,r); }` but when ran I get the error message in console saying `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'add'`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var callback = new Function(args, "context." + cbname + "(" + cbargs.toString() + ");");
```

Functions created with the Function constructor do not create closures to their creation contexts; they always run in the window context. And it's a form of eval, so it's better to avoid at all cost.

```
function A() {}
A.prototype = {
    register: function (name, context) {
        var callback = function () {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            args.shift();
            context[name].apply(context, args);
        };
        $(document).bind(name, callback);
    }
};

function B() {}
B.prototype = {
    add: function (l, r) {
        console.log(l + r);
    }
};

var a = new A(),
    b = new B();

a.register('add', b);
$(document).trigger('add', [2, 3]); // 5
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a much better way. I thought the distinction between data and code is blurred in this case in javascript, do you have any info about the performance of `Function` calls?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the first argument of a triggered event is the event itself.

So I think you'd need to change the line in your register function as follows:

```
args = ['evt', 'context'].concat(cbargs);
```

(jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hVGcE/3/)